# Sub-threading a Virtual Machine on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtual-machine

Salvete!  I am running Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows7 x64 machine, and have created a VM running the same (for sharepoint development).

I read [in this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35674/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-up-a-development-server-for-sharepoint) that there is a way that you can create "addon-disk" for a VM in such a way that you can join an addon-disk to the main drive, and then turn on and off those addon-disks.

What I want to do is to install Sharepoint on an addon-disk, and then turn it off if I don't want to load it, similar to what Mr. C.Marius describes in the above mentioned thread.

> When working with VHD boot you can create a Base disk on which you
>   install Windows+ drivers+ sql+..etc. and use it as the basis for
>   anything later. Use CREATE VDISK FILE="D:\W7_base.vhd" MAXIMUM=102400
>   TYPE=Expandable" - 100GB Max. (parent disk will never take all space,
>   but child disks will). Once you install all base SW you can create
>   multiple differential disks with stuff already installed, using (in
>   CMD > DISKPART) CREATE VDISK FILE=D:\VHD\W7_SP2010.vhd"
>   PARENT="D:\VHD\W7_Base.VHD" - this will get you the CHILD disk to
>   install ONLY SharePoint.
>
> Basically you would: create a new VHD (remember params), boot via your
>   USB bootable with W7, launch Diskpart, attach the VHD and simply run
>   Windows install. Once you're done you now have a BASE VHD (don't
>   change it anymore - ReadOnly). Simply reboot in USB again, run
>   DISKPART, create a NEW VHD using as PARENT the previous disk, use
>   BCDEDIT to update boot settings (clone entry and re-target the NEW VHD
>   -no longer the BASE) and from now on you only use this one for your work. If you need another configuration, make again new VHD with BASE
>   as PARENT. It sounds scary, now i do it in 20'

Can I do that with Oracle Virtual-Box?

Comment: Hmm.. two days!  I guess nobody has ever heard of doing this?  Maybe someone who is an expert with VirtualBox could at least tell me it can't be done?